# Why is it not show all informations as xml?

Tags: php, xml

PHP

```
$ch = curl_init() ;

$url = "http://www.espnfc.com/rss" ; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$xml = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 

$xmlTree = new simpleXMLElement($xml) ; 

echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($xmlTree->channel->item[0]) ;
echo "</pre>" ;
```

if i go on feed site there is title and pub date available it doesn't show in output, it is blank SimpleXMLElement Object. why is this formation not match with feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the magic syntax that SimpleXML uses, functions like `print_r()` and `var_dump()` will not always output all available data. They will still ne there if you access them. Use `SimpleXMLElement::asXML()` to fetch the serialized XML of an element node.

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
  var_dump($item->asXml());
}
```

It depends on your PHP version. Newer versions might output more data.

You can add an argument that avoids them (they get converted into normal text nodes).

```
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
   print_r($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The RSS from espnfc.com uses a lot of `<![CDATA[` in its code. That is what gives the problems of your output. We need to strip all the CDATA from the result before parse it into an xml object. I've written some code for you whit that does the trick.

```
$url = "http://www.espnfc.com/rss" ; 
$content = file_get_contents($url); // I replaced all your curl code with this
$rm_1 = str_replace("<![CDATA[","",$content);
$rm_2 = str_replace("]]>","",$rm_1);
$xmlTree = new simpleXMLElement($rm_2);
$feed = $xmlTree->channel->item[0];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($feed);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here is a code if you want to do it with Curl:

```
$ch = curl_init() ;

$url = "http://www.espnfc.com/rss" ; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$xml = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 

$rm_1 = str_replace("<![CDATA[","",$xml);
$rm_2 = str_replace("]]>","",$rm_1);

$xmlTree = new simpleXMLElement($rm_2) ; 

echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($xmlTree->channel->item[0]) ;
echo "</pre>" ;
```

**Edit 1:** Added code for Curl

Comment: Please don't just replace the CDATA section markers, they can contain unescaped special characters. The result can be an invalid/different XML.